# Document file path unreachable in swift

Tags: swift, documents, video-thumbnails

I'm currently working on a small swift application and I'm storing some video records in the documents folder of the app. I would like to retrieve these on a later moment. I already got an array of file locations like this:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6C462C4E-05E2-436F-B2E6-F6D9AAAC9361/Documents/videorecords/196F9A75-28C4-4B65-A06B-6111AEF85F01.mov
```

Now I want to use such file location to create a thumbnail with the first frame and connect that to my imageview with the following piece of code:

```
func createVideoStills() {
    for video in directoryContents {
        print("\(video)")
        do {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(video)"), options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
            let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
            videoCell.imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
            //let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The first print gives me a path like described above. But the AVURLAsset doesn't like this path because it spits out the following error:

> Error generating thumbnail: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100
>   "The requested URL was not found on this server."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on
>   this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x14ee29170 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Which is weird cause it is right there. Any solutions on how to fix/solve this?

Kind regards,

Wouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your `print("\(video)")` is not a file **path** but a string representation of file **URL**. You need to use `init(string:)` than `init(fileURLWithPath:)` of `NSURL`.

See what you get with:

```
            let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(string: video), options: nil)
```

(Unnecessary string interpolation would generate some unexpected result without errors -- like getting "Optional(...)", so you should avoid.)

Comment: Aah makes sense to me now. I was unnecessarily converting it. I already had an array with NSURL's. So didn't have to cast it. So stupid of me. I know that I was making a string representation out of the URL. All I had to do was the following:

`let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: video, options: nil)`

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

```
// if You Are Using PHPickerViewController then do this for fetching the url.
// ------
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
                        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }
                        if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
                                provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier, options: [:]) { [self] (videoURL, error) in
                                        print("resullt:", videoURL, error)
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                if let url = videoURL as? URL {
                                                        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                                                        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
                                                        playerVC.player = player
                                                        present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
```

Comment: This answer seems to be irrelevant to the question.